# MySQL transactions and the USE `database name` statement

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to specify the database to `use` for transactions, something like:

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
mysql_query("USE `database1`");
mysql_query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`");
mysql_query("COMMIT");
```

I can't find any reference about it, or the syntax (if it's possible), can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really hope you're not using the creaky, massively obsolete `mysql_query` in a new application.

Comment: mysql_select_db('database1');? or just spell it out all the way ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database1`.`table1`");

Comment: No tadman: very legacy app.

Comment: `Use database` isn't transactionable, only transnational statements are `SELECTs`, `UPDATEs` and `DELETEs`.

Answer (score 1):

`use` isn't transactionable:

```
mysql> use mysql;

Database changed
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use test;

Database changed
mysql> rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select database();
+------------+
| database() |
+------------+
| test       |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Note that it didn't go back to the `mysql` DB after the rollback